# Can't start docker

Tags: macos, docker

Does anyone know how I can fix this? On OSX. Docker doesn't start, the UI just says starting, the log file shows:

```
time="2016-08-31T20:01:26.092055332Z" level=debug msg="Failed to load layer sha256:04d69c4a99ea33d4859d57e4bb1b1d631a13251b7e5fcd490399ecd2a9296d60: failed to get diff id for sha256:04d69c4a99ea33d4859d57e4bb1b1d631a13251b7e5fcd490399ecd2a9296d60: invalid checksum digest format"
time="2016-08-31T20:01:26.238063289Z" level=debug msg="Failed to load layer sha256:770040782dd489c0921460f1c98f89553438ccd4403ee58bcce4eb048802858f: failed to get diff id for sha256:770040782dd489c0921460f1c98f89553438ccd4403ee58bcce4eb048802858f: invalid checksum digest format"
time="2016-08-31T20:01:26.243379288Z" level=debug msg="Failed to load layer sha256:7bf84ab6a09cab5a8596beffee90d2054b0945c9d82700d024704790c4510b17: failed to get diff id for sha256:7bf84ab6a09cab5a8596beffee90d2054b0945c9d82700d024704790c4510b17: invalid checksum digest format"
time="2016-08-31T20:01:26.285280816Z" level=debug msg="Failed to load layer sha256:acf1d45e95d3d09a9ac075159e4ca4e347c76d602c4f7490f38ed0b66c1d33e9: failed to get diff id for sha256:acf1d45e95d3d09a9ac075159e4ca4e347c76d602c4f7490f38ed0b66c1d33e9: invalid checksum digest format"
time="2016-08-31T20:01:26.322231488Z" level=debug msg="Failed to load layer sha256:edb4f7cbb0decb2e21f28404f4216e385944191fdb022831873feae88567ad8f: failed to get diff id for sha256:edb4f7cbb0decb2e21f28404f4216e385944191fdb022831873feae88567ad8f: invalid checksum digest format"
time="2016-08-31T20:01:26.353665824Z" level=debug msg="Max Concurrent Downloads: 3"
time="2016-08-31T20:01:26.354303999Z" level=debug msg="Max Concurrent Uploads: 5"
time="2016-08-31T20:01:26.495648503Z" level=debug msg="Cleaning up old mountid : start."
time="2016-08-31T20:01:26.496200149Z" level=fatal msg="Error starting daemon: layer does not exist"
```

Version 1.12.0-a (build: 11213)

Comment: how did you install docker? Homebrew? Docker.dmg?

Comment: I used the docker dmg.

Comment: did you install it as admin/root?

Comment: Don't really remember, it's been working for a few days so far - it's in /Applications so I guess so.

Comment: I'd recommend reinstalling at this point. Like I installed it through dmg and no probs.

Comment: The uninstaller in the app failed. Removing it from /Applications and running the install again wasn't enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this seems to have allowed it to start again:

```
$ rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.*
```